# How best to tell a background PHPprogram to stop

Tags: php

I wrote a long running PHP background program. There are times that I want it to stop, but stop gracefully,

What i did was, in the main logic loop I test for the existence of a file with a specific name. If the file exists the program stops. When I want the program to end itself, I just create that file.

Is there a more elegant way to do it.

I don't want to kill the process. I want the program to end itself.

Comment: you could implement a signal handler in your php file ( http://php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-signal.php ) and then interact with the process from your console using kill SIGHUP, kill SIGKILL, etc.

Comment: Yes, that is what I did. I test for the existence of a file stopProgramX

Answer (score 1):

As already suggested in comments, you can use a *signal* to terminate your process. The signal that you'll want to use is the `SIGTERM` signal (emphasis mine) [[ref](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_signal#POSIX_signals)]:

> The SIGTERM signal is sent to a process to **request its termination**. Unlike the SIGKILL signal, it can be caught and interpreted or ignored by the process. This allows the process **to perform nice termination releasing resources and saving state if appropriate**. SIGINT is nearly identical to SIGTERM.

For this, register a signal handler using the [`pcntl_signal`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-signal.php) function before starting your main loop.

```
declare(ticks = 1);
$stopProcess = FALSE;
pcntl_signal(SIGTERM, function() use (&$stopProcess) {
    echo "Received SIGTERM...\n";
    // Do further cleanup work either here or after the end of your main loop
    $stopProcess = TRUE;
});

while (!$stopProcess) {
    // main work loop
}

// Do cleanup work either here or in your signal handler
```

On the command line, you can use the `kill` executable to send the SIGTERM signal to your process:

```
$ kill -TERM <process id>
```